# findOneAndUpdate seems to work Robo 3T but POST request results in 'Pending' through Axios

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm a bit stumped and was wondering if anyone could help. Whenever I call an axios post, the network tab shows that the request is pending and ultimately fails. When I try the same call through Robo 3T, it updates succesfully.

Can anyone give me some insight? Thank you!

Here's the route I'm using:

```
router.post('/upvote/reply/id/:id',
    // passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), 
    async (req, res) => {
        await Posts.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "comments._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
            {
                $inc: { "comments.$.points": 1 },
                $push: { "comments.$.upvotedBy": req.user._id },
                $pull: { "comments.$.downvotedBy": req.user._id },
            },
            (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(404).json({
                        success: false,
                        error: err,
                        message: 'Post not upvoted!',
                    })
                }
                else {
                    return res.status(200).json({
                        success: true,
                        data: result
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
```

Here's how I'm calling my API route:

```
handleReplyUpvote = (id) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedReplies = prevState.replies.map(item => {
                if (item._id === id) {
                    try {
                        axios
                            .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/upvote/reply/id/${id}`)
                            .then(res => {
                                // console.log(res.data.data[0].comments[0])
                                console.log(res)
                                // ...item,
                                // const {posts} = this.state
                                // posts.push(res.data)
                                // this.setState({posts})
                            })
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    return {
                        ...item,
                        // voted: true,
                        points: item.points + 1
                    }
                }
                return item
            })
            return {
                replies: updatedReplies
            }
        })
        // console.log('boops')
    }
```

A little more context code which might help:

```
const replies = this.state.replies.slice().map((item, i) =>
            <div 
                key={i}
                className='replyItem'
            >
                <Reply
                    // key={i}
                    reply={item.reply}
                    id={item._id}
                    user_id={item.user_id}
                    createdAt={item.createdAt}
                    points={item.points}
                    handleDelete={() => this.handleDelete(item._id)}
                    user={this.props.auth}
                    handleReplyUpvote={() => this.handleReplyUpvote(item._id)}
                    // handleDownvote={() => this.handleReplyDownvote(item._id.points)}
                />
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: You are already using callback, so you should remove the `await` keyword. If this isn't enough to resolve your issue, show the axios code how you call this api.

Comment: @SuleymanSah hey there! thanks for the reply, I removed the await and I'm still running into issues unfortunately. I've updated the post above with some more code, let me know if there's anything else you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing async/await, promises and callbacks. Use either promises or asyns/await, not all. I have fixed few things and it should work. (I didn't test it though)

```
router.post("/upvote/reply/id/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await Posts.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "comments._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
            {
                $inc: { "comments.$.points": 1 },
                $push: { "comments.$.upvotedBy": req.user._id },
                $pull: { "comments.$.downvotedBy": req.user._id },
            }
        );
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            data: result,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            success: false,
            error: error.message,
            message: "Post not upvoted!",
        });
    }
});



handleReplyUpvote = async(id) => {
  const updatedReplies = [];
  for(const item of this.state.replies){
    if(item._id === id){
      try{
        const response = await axios
          .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/upvote/reply/id/${id}`)
        console.log(response.data);
      }catch(error){
        console.log(error.message);
      }
      updatedReplies.push({
        ...item,
        points: item.points + 1;
      })
      continue;
    }
    updatedReplies.push(item);
  }
  this.setState({
    replies: updatedReplies
  })
}
```